# Parameterise JUnit CucumberOptions through Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, automation, cucumber

I am busy with a BDD automation project that is coded in Java. We use Cucumber to run the BDD. The JUnit class that we use to kick off the run is as follows:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"usage", "json:target/cucumber.json", "html:target/cucumber", "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"},
        glue = {"BDD.step_definitions"},
        features = {"Unit-Tests\\Features"},
        dryRun = false,
        monochrome = false,
        strict = true
)
```

The issue that I am having is that I would like to parameterize the CucumberOptions through Jenkins, ideally setting the feature file or scenario name through a Jenkins choice parameter.

I am using AntBuild to build and test my project on Jenkins. Would it be possible to set the CucumberOptions on the build XML?

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in understanding how you can send arguments to the Java process you run in Jenkins.

Setting Cucumber options can be done like this:

`-Dcucumber.options="--help"`

If you are running from Maven, it would look like this:

`mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--help"`

Running a specific tag could be done like this:

`-Dcucumber.options="--tags @wip"`

More details can be found in the [Cucumber docs](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#running-cucumber) or in a [blog post](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/10/26/cucumber-tagging-scenarios) I wrote a while back.

Comment: Sorry it took me long to post this but your advice set me on the right path. I managed to add the options as java arguments for the Ant build step on Jenkins. So, thank you for that!